# ValueError: year is out of range using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

After I call candlestick_ohlc, I can't seem to convert the x axis dates to something matplotlib can understand.

I'm a noob Python programmer. I've tried turning the dataframe into a list, I've tried passing dates to candlestick_ohlc, nothing seems to work other than changing

```
 df['time'] = (df['time'].astype('float'))
```

into

```
df['time'] = (df['time'].astype('float')\1000)
```

Although that renders the wrong datetime.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
import matplotlib.style as style
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker


def get_data(date):
    """ Query the API for 2000 days historical price data starting from "date". """
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=2000&toTs={}".format(date)
    r = requests.get(url)
    ipdata = r.json()
    return ipdata

def get_df(from_date, to_date):
    """ Get historical price data between two dates. """
    date = to_date
    holder = []
    # While the earliest date returned is later than the earliest date requested, keep on querying the API
    # and adding the results to a list. 
    while date > from_date:
        data = get_data(date)
        holder.append(pd.DataFrame(data['Data']))
        date = data['TimeFrom']
    # Join together all of the API queries in the list.    
    df = pd.concat(holder, axis = 0)                    
    # Remove data points from before from_date
    df = df[df['time']>from_date]                       
    # Convert to timestamp to readable date format
    # df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')   
    # Make the DataFrame index the time
    df.set_index('time', inplace=True)                  
    # And sort it so its in time order 
    df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)        
    return df

df = get_df(1528502400, 1560112385)

style.use('dark_background')    
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
df = df.reset_index()

cols = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volumefrom', 'volumeto']
df = df[cols]

#IF YOU /1000 AFER ('float') IT WILL RUN BUT NOT CORRECT DATE
df['time'] = (df['time'].astype('float'))

print(df.dtypes)
ohlc = df.values.tolist()
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, width=.4, colorup='g', colordown='r')

# IF YOU COMMENT NEXT 4 LINES IT WILL RUN, but NO DATES for XAXIS
date_fmt = "%d-%m-%Y"
date_formatter = mdate.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax1.set_ylabel('BTC Price (USD)')
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

Expected result would be date labels plotted as d-m-y. :)

[Wish this had dates for xaxis labels not seconds since 1970](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfYpJ.png)

[This is what I want it to look like, but with accurate dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFQF.png)

Comment: When trying to run the code you've shared it is crashing. Can you please explicitly mention what inputs are you expecting ?

Comment: comment out starting from: >>date_fmt = "%d-%m-%Y" all the way to >>> fig.autofmt_xdate()   then it will run.

Comment: Matplotlib's datetime conversion is explained in [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html). it provides `matplotlib.dates.date2num()` which you would want to use here.

Comment: @WindSnowH20 Though I commented lines, as you mentioned, still it crashes  ```2019-06-11 07:40:48.907 python3[788:26257] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8af9e8ad90
2019-06-11 07:40:48.915 python3[788:26257] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8af9e8ad90'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: SOLVED - df['time'] = df['time'].apply(mdates.epoch2num)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to fix the code:

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(mdates.epoch2num)

It was definitely one of those lines of code that you spend hours on... now I know.